# Strange behaviour: Added object to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a strange behavior when adding an object to an ObservableCollection and then looking for it. Just after adding it is found and then with same code it isn't anymore?

```
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass(string s) {
        Str = s;
    }

    public string Str {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

    private ObservableCollection<TestClass> testCollection = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
    private List<string> newValueList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

private void Test() {
    var tmpList = newValueList.Select(p => new TestClass(p));

    foreach (var v in tmpList) {
        testCollection.Add(v);
        if (testCollection.Contains(v))
            Console.WriteLine("YES");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("NO");
    }

    foreach (var v in tmpList) {
        if (testCollection.Contains(v))
            Console.WriteLine("IN");
        else 
            Console.WriteLine("OUT");
    }
}
```

Running this code will result in the output: YES YES YES OUT OUT OUT

When using **`.ToList()`** to `tmpList` you will get the expected result.

Comment: You should implement Equals and GetHashCode in TestClass for those kind of comparsions. Without it you just compare references. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select method returns an IEnumerable object which calls GetEnumerator whenever its used in loop hence calling the Lambda in select method on every element in the list seprately for both loops.

Loop1: Select(p => new TestClass(p)) 
Loop2: Select(p => new TestClass(p))

so whenever the loop uses the tmpList 
for both loops select statement is executed which calls lambda

hence creating Distinct set of objects for every loop.

You can verify this behaviour by creating a breakpoint in the lambda expression.

You will see that its called 6 times not 3.

Comment: By the way this behavior has nothing to do with ObservableCollection its has to do with the implementation of Select method of LINQ to objects.

Comment: thanks, I think this is the best explanation what really happens

Answer (score 2):

You defined a class that runtime does not know how to compare them. So it assumes that two of them are equal when they have same reference not same `Str`. In another word two object of your `TestClass` (`a`,`b`) are equal when `a` and `b` are same addresses. If you want to change this and make `a` and `b` equal when they have same `Str` you should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. [You can read more here](http://www.aaronstannard.com/overriding-equality-in-dotnet/) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Part one:**

```
foreach (var v in tmpList) {
    testCollection.Add(v);
    if (testCollection.Contains(v))
        Console.WriteLine("YES");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("NO");
}
```

here you are adding `v` to collection and check if `v` is inside it so it will return "YES".

**Part Two**

```
foreach (var v in tmpList) {
    if (testCollection.Contains(v))
        Console.WriteLine("IN");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("OUT");
}
```

here you are looking for v (which is not the exact same reference to objects in your collection (because lazy evaluation generates new instance in foreach iterations every time)) in your collection so it will return "OUT"!

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to explicitly mention that `tmpList` is evaluated lazily, so each time it's iterated over it's creating new instances of `TestClass`, which is why the reference equality fails.  If `ToList()` was added to the `tmpList` line, it would start printing "OUT" as expected.

Comment: I also think that the real problem is the lazy iterator creating new objects. I'm not comparing the adresses of the variables (v), I'm comparing the addresses where they are pointing to (adress of the objects). Otherwise code like this would result in false, but the result is true: var a=v; var b=v; return a==b; Furthermore, using .ToList() works like expected using the same comparison. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `tmpList` is not a list, but a "lazy" iterator which will create new objects each time you `foreach` it.

Correct the line:

```
var tmpList = newValueList.Select(p => new TestClass(p)).ToList();
```